# Writing large array to file in python

Tags: python, numpy, printing, writefile

i have torch model about 1.7 gb and i try to write this model to file or print. Codes are as follows:

```
import numpy
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)
import torchfile
o = torchfile.load('ptn_comb.t7')
#print o
numpy.savetxt("test.txt",o)
```

When i deleted the "numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)" print and savetxt run properly and terminated in 10-15 minutes. However, with "numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)" 
even if script runs two hours, it is not terminated and test.txt is always empty.

How can i solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Printoptions will affect the `print o`, but shouldn't affect the `savetxt` step.

Answer (score 0):

Without the `threshold` change, the `print o` will summarize the output (default is 1000).  After it is done (relatively fast), the `savetxt` can act.  It does not use the `printoptions`.  It just iterates on the rows (1st dim) and writes a formatted string to the file.

With `threshold` set to `nan` `print` does not summarize.  Evidently the array is so large that it takes a very long time to format, and eventually print.  And it doesn't get around to the `savetxt` step.